# Python: Why does my SMTP script freeze my computer?

Tags: python, multithreading, smtp, freeze

So I wrote a little multithreaded SMTP program.  The problem is every time I run it, it freezes the computer shortly after.  The script appears to still work, as my network card is still lighting up and the emails are received, but in some cases it will lock up completely and stop sending the emails.

Here's a link to my two script files.  The first is the one used to launch the program:

[readFile.py](http://pastebin.com/bpg45YXg)
[newEmail.py](http://pastebin.com/44ja5gy8)

Comment: Do Not use pastebin for referencing code!

Comment: because pastebim data is volatile

Comment: @RestRisiko Care to explain why?  (Sorry if it's a noobish question)

Comment: dude, stuff on pastebin is removed after some days...we *don't* want dangling references to external resources on SO...got it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're using `popen` which creates subprocesses, ie. processes not threads. I'll assume this is what you meant.

My guess would be that the program gets stuck in a loop where it generates processes continuously, which the OS will probably dislike. (That kind of thing is known as a [forkbomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forkbomb) which is a good way to freeze Linux unless a process limit has been set with `ulimit`.) I couldn't find the bug though, but if I were you, I'd log messages each time I spawn or kill a subprocess, and if everything is normal, watch the system closely (`ps` or `top` on Unix systems) to see if the processes are really being killed.

Comment: Hrm, maybe I'll do this.  I guess I'll have to go with the former though (writing to a log file), since the system gets locked up and I'd be unable to run ps.

Comment: My idea was to run it before it freezes. Actually, it would be way cleaner to use `ulimit` to limit the number of processes (`ulimit -u`) to prevent the crash.

Comment: Dan: if this answer ends up being useful, you should vote it up (with the up arrow), if it answers your question, you should "accept" the answer, by clicking the check mark under the arrows. Both you and the answerer will gain reputation from this.

Comment: @Wilduck I tried to upvote it but I don't have enough rep yet.